# Can I call a stored procedure with hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, stored-procedures

I am bit new with hibernate and do not know how to call a stored procedure using hibernate.
I have the following details about the stored procedure.

```
Env : xxx
DB :  xxx
Database : xxxxx

Stored Proc : spCwebCloneSite
Input : SiteId int (existing site id)
NewSiteId int (new site id)
```

Now I have both the existing and new site id. But I do not know how I map it using Hibernate.

Comment: i solve it.    Query query = getSession().createSQLQuery("exec spCwebCloneSite ? , ?")
      .addEntity(CwSite.class)
      .setInteger(0, orignalSiteId.intValue())
      .setInteger(1, cloneSiteID.intValue());
      return query.executeUpdate()+"";

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;



public class StoredProc {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Session session = null;

        CallableStatement callableStatement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;

        try{

            SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();

            System.out.println("selecting records");

            callableStatement = session.connection().prepareCall("{call getRecords}");
            callableStatement.execute();

            resultSet = callableStatement.getResultSet();

            while(resultSet.next()){
                System.out.println(resultSet.getInt(1));
                System.out.println(resultSet.getString(2));
            }



            System.out.print("OK");

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            session.flush();
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```